# how to split text with regex match

Tags: javascript, regex

starting from this kind of text;

```
var txt = "hello [a14] world, and [b74] some more [h85], ..."
```

I expect as result

```
var arr = 
  [ "hello "
  , "[a14]"
  , " world, and "
  , "[b74]"
  , " some more "
  , "[h85]"
  , ", ..."
  ]
```

what I have tried so far, but mastering regular expressions is still difficult for me...

```js
let txt = "hello [a14] world, and [b74] some more [h85], ..."

let arr = txt.match(/(\[(.*?)\])|(.*?)/g)

console.log( arr )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also try splitting on lookarounds:

```js
var text = "hello [a14] world, and [b74] some more [h85], ...";
var arr = text.split(/(?=\[)|(?<=\])/);
console.log(arr);
```

The logic here is to split the string whenever what follows is `[` or what precedes in `]`.  Note that lookarounds are zero width, and so the pattern `(?=\[)|(?<=\])` matches but does not actually consume any text in the input while splitting.

Comment: I choose this one because this solution always returns an array, even when the string is empty, and doesn't give an empty string at the start or end when the text starts or ends with a `[cod]`

Answer (score 3):

You can try `/(\[[^\]\[]*\]|[^\]\[]+)/g`. The differences are:

- used `+` instead of `*` to grab at least once character and avoid matching empty strings
- `[^\]\[]` gives you "any character not brackets" so you can avoid non-greedy matching with `?`
- shifted capturing groups around to be more intuitive

```js
const txt = "hello [a14] world, and [b74] some more [h85], ...";
console.log(txt.match(/(\[[^\]\[]*\]|[^\]\[]+)/g));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `.split()`. The trick is to capture the split condition, it will show up in the resulting array:

```js
let txt = "hello [a14] world, and [b74] some more [h85], ..."
let regex = /(\[[^\]]*\])/;
let result = txt.split(regex);
console.log(result);
```

Output:

```
[
  "hello ",
  "[a14]",
  " world, and ",
  "[b74]",
  " some more ",
  "[h85]",
  ", ..."
]
```

Explanation:

- `(` - capture group start
- `\[` - scan over `[`
- `[^\]]*` - scan over eanything not `]`
- `\]` - scan over `]`
- `)` - capture group end

UPDATE based on comment:

Whitespace can be trimmed by changing above regex to `/ *(\[[^\]]*\])  */`

Comment: Ah, that can easily be trimmed using `/ *(\[[^\]]*\])  */`